# Paypal iOS SDK get user profile information from the future payment consent

Tags: ios, paypal

I have been wondering how I can get the user's consent to give information (name, email, etc) from the future payment consent dialog once they have logged in using the mobile sdk. Right now when I implement the future payment consent, it does not ask the user to share their information and does not return anything related to the user. I have however noticed in apps like Munchery, the consent UI after the user logs in asks the user both for future payment consent and to share their name and email. All of this is done on one form with wording different than what seems to be available in the current SDK.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425355/paypal-email-id-of-the-user-who-has-approved-future-payment) but using the profile sharing view controller displays an entirely separate login and consent form which ends up requiring two log ins in a row. Is it still possible in the version 2.0 SDK to get future payment and profile information consent at the same exact time from a user? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28457701/2184893) is correct but is just not very helpful so here's how we did it.

The [Profile Sharing Mobile Integration](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/profile_sharing_mobile.md) feature of Paypal does exactly what you want - authorize future payments and return user information in the same call. You can do it all in one login flow. The user does see an additional screen that displays the scopes requested by the app, but does not have to go through a second login.

Here is the code snippet we've used:

```
func profileController() -> PayPalProfileSharingViewController {
    PayPalMobile.preconnectWithEnvironment(PayPalEnvironmentSandbox)//PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork)
    let scope: Set<String> = Set([kPayPalOAuth2ScopeEmail, kPayPalOAuth2ScopeFuturePayments])
    let controller = PayPalProfileSharingViewController(scopeValues: scope, configuration: self.paypalConfiguration!, delegate: self)
    return controller!
}

func payPalProfileSharingViewController(profileSharingViewController: PayPalProfileSharingViewController, userDidLogInWithAuthorization profileSharingAuthorization: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    self.processAuthorization(profileSharingAuthorization)
}

func userDidCancelPayPalProfileSharingViewController(profileSharingViewController: PayPalProfileSharingViewController) {
    self.delegate?.didFailPayPalConsent()
}

func processAuthorization(authorization: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {
    if let authCode = authorization["response"]?["code"] as? String {
        self.delegate?.didSucceedPayPalConsent(authCode)
    }
    else {
        self.delegate?.didFailPayPalConsent()
    }
}
```

Edit: The mobile controller gives you the auth token that has permissions for profile information, but you have to make another call from your server side code for that information:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#get-user-information